# How merge two list of objects and identify identical elements

Tags: kotlin

I have 2 lists containing objects of the same type and I am looking to merge these 2 lists.

Let's take an example:

List1 contains `[A, B, C, E]`

List2 contains `[A, D]`

what I need `[A, B, C, E, D]`

**I absolutely want the identical elements (here the object A) to be those of my list 1.**

*It does not matter if the order of the items is not kept.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep identical elements from list1, you should not use `distinct`. Your code should be explicit on this business rule to avoid future errors.

An example :

```
class Elt(private val id: Int, private val content: String) {

    open fun equals(other: Elt): Boolean {
        return this.id == other.id
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "$id -> $content"
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val l1 = listOf(Elt(1,"L1"), Elt(2,"L1"), Elt(3,"L1"), Elt(4,"L1"))
    val l2 = listOf(Elt(1,"L2"), Elt(5,"L2"))

    val l4 = l2 + l1
    println(l4.distinct()) // Elt 1 comes from L2

    val l5 = l1 + l2
    println(l5.distinct()) // Elt 1 comes from L1

    val l6 = l2.toMutableList().apply { addAll(l1) }.distinct()
    println(l6.distinct()) // Elt 1 comes from L2
}
```

It will print:

```
[1 -> L1, 2 -> L1, 3 -> L1, 4 -> L1, 1 -> L2, 5 -> L2]
[1 -> L2, 5 -> L2, 1 -> L1, 2 -> L1, 3 -> L1, 4 -> L1]
[1 -> L1, 2 -> L1, 3 -> L1, 4 -> L1, 1 -> L2, 5 -> L2]
[1 -> L2, 5 -> L2, 1 -> L1, 2 -> L1, 3 -> L1, 4 -> L1]
```

If you remove duplicate in `list2` before adding the elements, you will ensure that you keep identical ielement from `list1`:

```
    val l3 = l1 + (l2 - l1.intersect(l2))
    println(l3)
```

Comment: thank you very much for all the tests. Indeed I have just tried your solution which seems to me more suitable for objects and not primitive types.

Answer (score 3):

Simple case:

```
val lista = listOf( 1,2,3 )
val listb = mutableListOf( 1,4,5 ).apply { addAll(lista) }.distinct()
// result listb -> [1, 4, 5, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

To add two string list

```
val a = listOf("a","b" ,"c" , "e")
val b = listOf("a", "d")
val c = a + b
```

To have only distinct values,

```
val d = c.distinct()
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the above solutions: use `HashSet`. `Set` collections don't support multiple occurrences of the same element so when you add `A` twice, the second one simply gets discarded.

```
var s: HashSet<String> = HashSet<String>()
s.addAll(listOf("A", "B", "C", "E"))
s.addAll(listOf("A", "D"))
var l = s.toList()
```

Since `HashSet` uses hashing under the hood, you get O(1) complexity on most of its operations.

Comment: LinkedHashSet if you want to keep the order of original lists.